# inject spring bean on spring schedular

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

i want to schedule a method using spring. After referring this [example](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/)

i configured my applicationcontext file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
            ">  
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.ankit.schedular"/>

    <task:annotation-driven/>


    <bean id="vendor" class="com.ankit.schedular.SchedularService"/>      

</beans>
```

But, I am getting following exception

```
2017-03-14 17:12:18 ERROR ContextLoader:318 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.ankit.schedular.SchedularService] for bean with name 'vendor' defined in class path resource [service.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ankit.schedular.SchedularService
```

my SchedularService class is defined as

```
public class SchedularService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SchedularService.class);


    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void cronJob(){
        logger.info("Entered");
        logger.info(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        logger.info("Exit");
    }
}
```

Since, i don't require to make any controller, i didn't declare dispatcher servlet on my web.xml

Can you suggest what is going wrong here ?

**EDIT: Adding web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/service.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: share your web.xml

Comment: `CannotLoadBeanClassException` refers to the missing class on the classpath. Check if classpath include the `SchedularService` and also try re-build via IDE or maven (*or any other tool being used*)